# Does the function has a limit a $x_0$?

Tags: limits

> Let $f :D\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $x_0$ as an accumulation point of $D\subseteq \mathbb{R}$. Prove that $f$ has a limit at $x_0$ if for each $\epsilon > 0$, there is a neighborhood $Q$ of $x_0$ such that, for any $x, y \in Q\cap D$,$x\neq x_0 , y\neq x_0$ , we have $|f (x)−f (y)|< \epsilon$.

Any hint to this question will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $x_0$ is an accumulation point there is s sequence $(x_n)$ in $D\cap Q$ with limit $x_0$. Show that $f(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence. So $l=\lim f(x_n)$ exists. Can you now show that $f(x) \to l$ as $x \to x_0$?

Comment: The last part can be done, by giving a contrapositive argument, where I claim that, $f(x)\not\rightarrow l$, where $x\rightarrow x_0$, then $f(x_n)$ does not converge, where $x_n\rightarrow x_0$.

Comment: Chandramauli.Can you show that $f(x) \rightarrow L$ as $x \rightarrow x_0$.